# Force decimal value, even when 0 in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, decimal

I have a field that stores version information such as 1.1, 1.2 etc. However, it will store 4.0 as 4 and 5.0 as 5.

Is there a way to force it to show the .0?

I have tried NUMBER(5, 3) and DECIMAL(5, 3) data types and neither work.

Version - Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `NUMBER` column will never store the decimal value if it doesn't need to.

You can, however, control how the data is displayed to the user when it is converted to a string by using an explicit `TO_CHAR` rather than relying on implicit data type conversion.  If you use the format mask `9.0` in your `TO_CHAR` call, for example, the string that is generated will always have 1 decimal digit.

```
SQL> select to_char( 4, '9.0' )
  2    from dual;

TO_C
----
 4.0

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select to_char( 4.1, '9.0' )
  2*   from dual
SQL> /

TO_C
----
 4.1
```

That being said, it seems unlikely that you would really want to store software version information in a `NUMBER` column rather than a `VARCHAR2`.  You, presumably, aren't doing any mathematical operations on the data so most of the benefit of having a `NUMBER` is off the table.  And software versions are not inherently numeric.  You often find yourself wanting more than two components (i.e. Oracle 11.2.0.1).  And software versions tend to have highly non-numeric things done to them.  If the version that follows 4.9 is 4.10, that's very different than the version 4.1 that followed 4.0.  If you're using a `NUMBER`, though, you lose the ability to differentiate between those versions.

Comment: I feared as much. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: @hacket - also note that `DECIMAL` and `NUMBER` are the same thing. There's a StackOverflow post about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031409/decimals-p-or-numbers-p), and it includes a reference to the Oracle docs. If you specify a column as `DECIMAL`, Oracle will create it as a `NUMBER`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hide this from your code, create a view to hide these details.

It will however, be a string for the same reason Justin indicates.