# Function dont return decimal places

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have an Oracle function that performs calculations, but didn't return the decimal of the result.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function MY_TESTE
   RETURN DECIMAL
   IS
BEGIN

  RETURN 1/3;

END;
```

If I executed the function

```
SELECT MY_TESTE 
  FROM DUAL
```

It return the value 0 with any decimal places. But it expect to return 0.3333
Any ideas ?

Comment: Not familiar with Oracle SQL, but in T-SQL the return type of a division is the same as the type of the arguments. That is, integer.

Answer (score 5):

DECIMAL is declared in the package SYS.STANDARD as a subtype of NUMBER (as are most numeric types in Oracle), specifically as NUMBER(38, 0), which means that DECIMAL values are not able to have digits to the right of the decimal point.  In order to have DECIMAL values with numbers to the right of the decimal point they have to be declared as such, similar to

```
dValue  DECIMAL(38, 4)
```

However, this won't help if you want to return such a value from a function, because you can't have precision specifiers on a function return type.

In order to have a DECIMAL value with digits to the right of the decimal place returned from a function you need to declare a subtype of DECIMAL that specifies the correct number of decimal places and use that subtype as the return type of your function.  Here's an example:

```
DECLARE 
  SUBTYPE DEC_10_3 IS DECIMAL(10, 3);

  FUNCTION TEST1 RETURN DECIMAL
  IS
    d  DECIMAL := 1/3;
  BEGIN
    RETURN d;
  END TEST1;

  FUNCTION TEST2 RETURN DECIMAL
  IS
    d  DECIMAL(10, 3) := 1/3;
  BEGIN
    RETURN d;
  END TEST2;

  FUNCTION TEST3 RETURN DEC_10_3 IS
    d DEC_10_3 := 1/3;
  BEGIN
    RETURN d;
  END TEST3;
BEGIN
  -- Test statements here
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TEST1=' || TEST1);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TEST2=' || TEST2);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TEST3=' || TEST3);
END;
```

Running the above will produce

```
TEST1=0
TEST2=0
TEST3=.333
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

Change the return type to `NUMBER`

Here you have explained the difference between DECIMAL and NUMBER datatype in Oracle: [decimal(s,p) or number(s,p)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031409/decimals-p-or-numbers-p)

Comment: The major problem is that i can declare the return value with decimal places, like CREATE OR REPLACE Function MY_TESTE RETURN DECIMAL(18,4) IS BEGIN RETURN 1/3; END;

Comment: So the answer of @Bob Jarvis is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

in Oracle DECIMAL is like integer by default
for storage division result you need decimal(10, 3) for example

```
declare
    l_res1 decimal(10, 3);
    l_res2 decimal;
begin

    l_res1 := 1 / 3;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_res1);

    l_res2 := 1 / 3;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_res2);
end;
```

but you cant use decimal(10, 3) as returned type in you function so change decimal to number

good luck

Comment: The major problem is that i can declare the return value with decimal places, like 
CREATE OR REPLACE Function MY_TESTE
   RETURN DECIMAL(18,4)
   IS
BEGIN

  RETURN 1/3;

END;

Comment: try to use this function in select ;)

Comment: @RuiSoares - I suspect you meant '...**can't** declare the return value with decimal place...".  That's why in my answer I declared a subtype of DECIMAL, then had one of the functions return that subtype.  It's a bit awkward, but in PL/SQL that's how it has to be done.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: subtype is great solution, I forget about this feature )

Answer (score 0):

Bob Jarvis has explained the problem with using `DECIMAL`. You can use `TRUNC` (or `ROUND`, depending on how you want it to behave) and return a `NUMBER` that's still restricted to the required number of decimal places:

```
create or replace function my_test return number is
begin
  return trunc(1/3, 4);
end;
/

select my_test from dual;

   MY_TEST
----------
    0.3333
```

The difference between `TRUNC` and `ROUND` is better demonstrated with a different fraction:

```
create or replace function my_test return number is
begin
  return trunc(2/3, 4);
end;
/

select my_test from dual;

   MY_TEST
----------
    0.6666 

create or replace function my_test return number is
begin
  return round(2/3, 4);
end;
/

select my_test from dual;

FUNCTION MY_TEST compiled
   MY_TEST
----------
    0.6667
```

Notice the last version rounds the last digit up in this version.